# How does this affect one’s Nakshatra?

Tags: shiva, trinity, horoscopes, nakshatra

I have Purvabhadrapada as my moon. And I am really trying to learn about this deity and ajaikad. I have a good side and a bad side. My anger is bad and impulsive. And I have bad clots and issues with my left leg. Only my right leg is good. I feel a deep connection and even when I converted to Hinduism 14 years ago I went to shiva.

Comment: Without a complete look at the birth(Rasi) chart and other divisional charts, signs planets are placed in , which lord occupies which house, which dashas are currently in effect, as mentioned in ancient Jyotisha Texts its impossible to pinpoint anything.Millions of ppl can have their moon in purvabhadrapada nakshatra, can all of their karmic imprints from previous lives be same???

Comment: I agree with you. I just meant there is a connection there. That’s all. Like I gravitated back to my soul group or something lol. I am studying it and evening looking at the d-11 chart and stuff like that. It’s a lot but I love it. Jupiter does rule my chart and I have my sun in ashleesha. Also always close to shiva. I read that on one site. Pretty cool.